# Azure Pipelines DevOps Not Being Triggered by PR

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

I've been using [Azure Pipelines](https://dev.azure.com/stumpy-dev/stumpy/_build?definitionId=2&_a=summary) for a while now and haven't changed my `azure-pipelines.yml` file [here](https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml) in 2 months. Previously, when there was a new PR, the pipeline would trigger and cause the environment to be built and the tests would be run.

Today, there was a [new PR](https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/pull/142) but I noticed that the pipeline was not being triggered. Then, to further test this, I forked, cloned, and branched the repository myself and created another [new PR](https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/pull/144) and, again, the pipeline was not triggered.

It's not clear to me where things are getting stuck and it's not clear how one would debug this. I've gone through [this Azure DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#my-pipeline-isnt-triggering) but it wasn't useful. I can manually trigger the pipeline to execute and test the master branch but I don't know how to manually trigger the same thing for a PR. Here's [my Azure DevOps page for reference](https://dev.azure.com/stumpy-dev/stumpy/_build?definitionId=2&_a=summary).

Comment: Did you try adding a `pr` section to your yaml? It should not be required, but maybe the implicit trigger is broken somehow... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

Comment: Thanks @AlexAIT. That did the trick. Something definitely changed on Azure as this was affecting a lot of other people at the same time

Comment: We has fixed now, and has released to all regions. You can continue work as before, even none of `pr` configured in YAML.

Answer (score 0):

As normal, you do not need config `pr` in YAML script if there's no any special demand, we would do pull request trigger for all branches. But, it [start broken from 03-13 21:02 (UTC),](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/179641421) which **caused by us**, you do not do anything wrong.

*The fix is preparing with our best.*

As Alex said, this is the implicit trigger which YAML support only, if you do not configure `pr` in YAML explicitly.

---

To avoid such stuck later, except the method that Alex mentioned: add `pr` into YAML. You can also make use of UI configuration which performance is very stable until now.

Just go `Pipeline definition` page => Click on **`three dots`** of right corner => Select `Trigger`:

[image]

Then you will see `Triggers` tab which has `Continues integration` and `Pull request validation` display below. Open `Pull request validation` and enable `Override the YAML pull request trigger from here`:

[image]

*Additional, Our team has noticed this broken issue, will update whether it is fixed here once we have any fixed release in progress.*

---

**Update 3/18/2020:**

Fixed has released to all region. Every one can work `github pr trigger` as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) shows now.